# Update app to Marshmallow or Nougat

Tags: android, android-permissions

I had my app targeting Lollipop where permissions are granted at installation time.
Then I target to Nougat (I skipped Marshmallow because I didn't have time in the last year) so I had to create the permission request at runtime right after installation. That is ok, it took me a bit of time but the app asks for them without any problem and behaves correctly if one is not granted.

But, my problem is:
I had thousands of users with the app installed, now, after the update they are asked to grant the permissions again, even when they were already granted before the update. The results is that I am losing a lot of users every day. They think that the app is asking for new permissions. It is hard to me to explain to them that those permissions were granted before the update and the app was not "dangerous", in fact, many of those users have used the app for years, but now they just don't trust.

So, my question is: Can I rollback in someway?
Can I make playstore respect the permissions that were already granted before the update?
I understand that the runtime permissions should be for new installs, not for updates. I think google did it wrong here (again).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. That's a pain, I agree, but precisely what Google wants is to get rid of that scheme of granting permissions at install time then never asking again.

The best thing you could do imho is to control the situation a little and detect if permissions are granted at boot time and, if they are not, direct the user to a fancy activity where you tell the user about your frustration with google, and that he/she needs to authorize the permissions again for his/her own security etc ...

You can use something like this

```
    /**
     * Check the application has Permissions
     *
     * @param context App context
     * @return Whether
     */

   static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String[] permissions) {
        for (String p : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, p) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and then query for arbitrary permissions:

```
boolean hasMyPermissions = hasPermissions (context, {
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    });

  if (!hasMyPermissions) {

       // open a cool activity / fragment / etc with graphics, fancy text, etc.. then
       // ask the user for permissions
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, permissions, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

  }
```

You will get the callback in `onRequestPermissionsResult`:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // permissions: Same String[] with your req permissions
        // grantresults: wether each individual permission has been granted or not
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't understand the problem. I had my app installed in 50000 devices. It was targeting Lollipop. Then I modified it, set it to target Nougat and ask for the permissions at runtime. It works well but the problem is that it asks for the permissions to those 50000 already installed devices. Because once updated, the app has not permissions granted so it asks for them. This made many users to dislike the app because they were thinking that the app was asking for new permissions. Users don't remember what permissions were granted when they first installed it.

Comment: I understand your problem. Unfortunately there is no solution (afaik). I suggest you to somehow take control of the permission re-grant by displaying a custom UI and inform your users. Otherwise, tell your users to downgrade to Lollipop :(

Comment: So, as I said, Google took a terrible decision this time (once again)